# Jquery Datatable Sorting concern

Tags: datatables

I have datatable with server side processing as true. The table has 5 columns. The sorting for all columns happen at server side. But i want only one column of that table to be sorted by client side. How do I achieve this?

Comment: show some code, if not, we dont know what actually you done